# How to merge contextmanager and asynccontextmanager into one decorator?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

**Solved this myself while writing up the question**. Rubber duck debugging triumphs again.

I'd like to decorate a generator for use as both a context manager and as an async context manager. Right now I'm wrapping one in the other

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager, asynccontextmanager

@contextmanager
def sync_manager():
    yield

@asynccontextmanager
async def async_manager():
    with sync_manager():
        yield
```

but this means the caller needs to specify whether it's the sync or async version they're after. I'd like to avoid that. Now

- `contextmanager` works by wrapping the function in a `_GeneratorContextManager` object with `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods, while
- `asynccontextmanager` works by wrapping the function in a `_AsyncGeneratorContextManager` object with `__aenter__` and `__aexit__` methods.

Since these are distinct, I should be able to write one decorator that implements both protocols. I've made a few attempts at this without luck. What's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 4):

Solution:

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager, asynccontextmanager
from functools import wraps

class MaybeAsyncGeneratorContextManager:

    def __init__(self, func, args, kwargs):
        self._func = func
        self._args = args
        self._kwargs = kwargs
        self._sync = None
        self._async = None

    def __enter__(self):
        if self._sync is None:
            syncfunc = contextmanager(self._func)
            self._sync = syncfunc(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
        return type(self._sync).__enter__(self._sync)

    def __exit__(self, t, v, tb):
        return type(self._sync).__exit__(self._sync, t, v, tb)

    def __aenter__(self):
        if self._async is None:
            @asynccontextmanager
            async def asyncfunc(*args, **kwargs):
                with contextmanager(self._func)(*args, **kwargs):
                    yield 
            self._async = asyncfunc(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
        return type(self._async).__aenter__(self._async)

    def __aexit__(self, t, v, tb):
        return type(self._async).__aexit__(self._async, t, v, tb)

def maybeasynccontextmanager(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def helper(*args, **kwds):
        return MaybeAsyncGeneratorContextManager(func, args, kwds)
    return helper
```

I originally used the internal `_GeneratorContextManager` and `_AsyncGeneratorContextManager` classes directly, but getting the right behaviour on errors was tricky. This way adds another layer of indirection, but handles errors properly.

Comment: Though your code work, `__enter__` and `__exit__`, and their async friends should be called using `type(self._sync).__enter__(self._sync)` as specified by PEP 343: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/#specification-the-with-statement and PEP 492: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#new-syntax

Comment: I'm afraid my Python knowledge is failing me - what's the importance of `type(x).method(x)` here vs `x.method()`?

Comment: `x.method` can be replaced by `x.method = another_function`. These PEPs seem discouraging modifying the behaviors of context managers in individual instances.

Comment: Thanks for explaining - I've edited my code to match the PEP.

Comment: Is there a way to make this work when the wrapped function needs to be an async function? I'm guessing this gets much harder with the pervasiveness of async.